# want to use count function in sql by joining 3 tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to answer this query:

> "Print the total number of projects controlled by the different departments and the manager of the project."

I am using following query,

```
select a.dname as "Departement", b.fname as "Manager", c.pname as "Project" , c.dnum
from "DEPARTMENT " a ,
     "EMPLOYEE " b ,
     "PROJECT " c
where a.dnumber = c.dnum
  and a.mgr_ssn = b.ssn ;
```

I just want to add count function to return me the number of projects controlled by each manager.

Comment: Hint: When you read "_total number_", `COUNT()` will be involved, and probably `GROUP BY` too.

Comment: Whoever taught you to join like that should consider quitting... Explicit joins are the standard now

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: you are asking for this, select a.dname as "Departement", b.fname as "Manager", c.pname as "Project" , c.dnum from "DEPARTMENT " a 
join "EMPLOYEE " b on b.ssn = a.mgr_ssn
join "PROJECT " c on c.dnum = a.dnumber;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, that's not how you join tables, at least not since the early nineties.

Then, you want a single row for each `department` and `manager`, regardless of how many `projects` they have associated; this means you need to `group by` those two fields. The other information is the aggregation of the `projects` rows, and the aggregation you need is, as you said, the `count`.

Your final query should look like this

```
select  a.dname as "Departement",
        b.fname as "Manager",
        count(distinct c.pname) as "ProjectsCount"
from    DEPARTMENT a
join    EMPLOYEE b
on      a.mgr_ssn = b.ssn
join    PROJECT c
on      a.dnumber = c.dnum
group by a.dname, b.fname
```

Comment: sql99 calls it valid, and it's how a lot of DBAs join tables still - including myself :) - though i'd worry about the implied spaces in the table names.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped! @BryanNewman what's the reason you use that kind of joins? I only see downsides in that...

Comment: That old, implicit join is still valid in SQL 2016, but that's no excuse to use it.

Comment: in that case i'd really consider dropping your double quotes from the whole query.

Comment: Old habits... It took me years to switch to modern, explicit JOIN, but now I'll never go back!

Comment: @jarlh as long as you only include join conditions in the ON clause, it's all good. I see far too much that should be in the WHERE clause inside the join. What a mess.

Comment: At a basic level the SELECT clause says which columns you want, the FROM clause says where from and how they link and the WHERE clause filters rows. If you stick to that you wont go too far wrong.

Comment: @StefanoZanini for brevity, and for keeping set limiting conditions all in one place. i like to have a list of all the entities involved together, which helps me imagine the cartesian product which I can then cull with a where clause the way Codd intended. The only benefit I see to explicit joins is being able to specify "left"

Comment: @BriteSponge "how they link" would be considered a set limiting condition until you make it inclusive with the keyword "LEFT"

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer and this one both assume no two projects have the same name - is there a unique key on the project table?

```
select a.dname as Departement, 
       b.fname as Manager, 
       c.pname as Project, 
       c.dnum,
       count(distinct d.pname)
from DEPARTMENT a,
     EMPLOYEE b,
     PROJECT c,
     PROJECT d
where a.dnumber = c.dnum
  and a.mgr_ssn = b.ssn
  and a.dnumber = d.dnum
group by a.dname, 
         b.fname, 
         c.pname, 
         c.dnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your query

```
   select a.dname as Department, b.fname as Manager, count(c.pname) as Project, c.dnum
     from DEPARTMENT  a 
     join EMPLOYEE    b on a.mgr_ssn = b.ssn 
     join PROJECT     c on a.dnumber = c.dnum 
     group by a.dname,b.fname,c.dnum
```